# Perl script giving different output on bash shell in Linux and /sbin/sh shell on HP unix

Tags: perl

Input:

```
tmp# cat test5
1234      012345
0.000             01234
01/02/03          5467
01234           0123
05554567       234
0099
0000           000054
```

Output on Bash Shell:

```
[tmp]# perl -lpe 's#(^|\h)\K0[^./\h]+(?=\h|$)#"$&"#g' test5
1234      "012345"
0.000             "01234"
01/02/03          5467
"01234"           "0123"
"05554567"       234
"0099"
"0000"           "000054"
```

Output on `/sbin/sh` shell on HP Unix:

```
/tmp # perl -lpe 's#(^|\h)\K0[^./\h]+(?=\h|$)#"$&"#g' test5
1234      012345
0.000             01234
01/02/03          5467
01234           0123
05554567       234
0099
0000           000054
```

Comment: The shell has nothing to do with it. What versions of Perl are you using on the two systems?

Comment: perl on ubuntu is 5.22 (from 2015) while my perl on hp-ux is 5.8.8 (from 2006). You may need to compile it.

Comment: I think this is the first time I have _ever_ seen `\h` used rather than `\s`. (I had to look it up.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to <del>write a letter</del> quote all integer values that begin with zero. This is a much simpler RE that achieves this aim:

```
perl -lpe '1 while (s/(^|\s)(0\d*)(\s|$)/$1"$2"$3/)' test5

1234      "012345"
0.000             "01234"
01/02/03          5467
"01234"           "0123"
"05554567"       234
"0099"
"0000"           "000054"
```

Answer (score 0):

The two machines are running different versions of Perl, and the difference in shells have nothing to do with it.

Perl on HP-UX is, [according to Archemar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404958/perl-script-giving-different-output-on-bash-shell-in-linux-and-sbin-sh-shell-on#comment724238_404958), Perl 5.8.8, and the positive look-behind escape `\K` and the `\h` escape for horizontal whitespace [were both added in Perl 5.10](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Regular-expressions).  *This* is why the two Perls give you different results.